# How to filter a dataframe by comparing two string vectors?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a data frame with two string vectors, e.g.

```
Xsz<-c("A", "B", "C")
Xal<-c("A|B", "A|C", "B|C")
XDF<-data.frame(Xsz,Xal)
```

I'd like to filter those rows, where the string in the first column (Xsz) appears in the second one (row 1 & 3 this case)

I've tried this:

```
XDF %>%
  filter(Xsz %in% Xal)
```

or this:

```
XDF %>%
  filter(grep(Xsz, Xal))
```

but they do something different.
The actual data frame is of course not 3 rows long, but like 60M... :-)

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to use `Xal` as pattern for regex. You can't easily use `grepl` for this because it searches one pattern at a time, and you have a vector of patterns. You can use `stringr::str_detect()` instead.

```r
library(tidyverse)       
Xsz<-c("A", "B", "C")
Xal<-c("A|B", "A|C", "B|C")
XDF<-data.frame(Xsz,Xal)  

XDF %>%
  filter(str_detect(Xsz, pattern = Xal))
#>   Xsz Xal
#> 1   A A|B
#> 2   C B|C
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That could go wrong with `str_detect("AA", pattern = "A|B")` which will return `TRUE`, depending on the OP's needs though.

Comment: @Merijn van Tilborg it's literally the solution he pointed at. I don't see any strings in `Xsz` with multiple characters. If he has strings with multiple characters he can just separate/split to different column and filter on them. I don't understand your concern here.

Comment: Not per se from the example, but "the string in the first column (Xsz) appears in the second one" does not tell us the string is always one letter and could easily be AA. You are matching if any letter from the pattern occurs in the string and not if the string matches (as requested in the text).

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! It seems to work perfectly.
But indeed, as Merijn mentioned, there are multiple-letter strings in the first column too, so the example was not the best.  The issue, you raised, that  str_detect("AA", pattern = "A|B")  will return TRUE seems to be relevant therefore. Why is it so? Because it understands "A|B" as "A" or "B"?

Comment: It wasn't obvious for me if that would have been a bug or a feature, as the case was not in the sample data. You should upvote those answers that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach would be to index using `apply` with `grepl` across rows:

```
XDF[apply(XDF, 1, function(x) grepl(x[2], x[1])),]

#  Xsz Xal
#1   A A|B
#3   C B|C
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `sapply` with `grepl` like this:

```r
XDF[diag(sapply(XDF$Xsz, \(x) grepl(x, XDF$Xal, fixed = TRUE))),]
#>   Xsz Xal
#> 1   A A|B
#> 3   C B|C
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you need full matches, you could do

```
XDF %>% group_by(Xsz) %>% filter(Xsz %in% strsplit(Xal, "|")[[1]])
```

**results**

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Groups:   Xsz [2]
  Xsz   Xal  
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     A|B  
2 C     B|C
```

**data**

```
XDF <- data.frame(
  Xsz = c("A", "B", "C", "AA"),
  Xal = c("A|B", "A|C", "B|C", "A|B")
)
```